# touchesEnded with array of UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, touchesbegan

I have an array with UIImageView. Let's say currently there's 5 UIImageView in the array. How do I know which UIImageView i'm currently touching?

Thanks.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch view] == ??)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of most simple solution is to set `tag` properties of the views.

```
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger tag
```

This way you can easily retrieve the one touched :

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([[touch view] tag] == 1)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

}

You can set this property either in Interface Builder, or in code directly.

Comment: how about if i want to know whether the user is touching any of the UIImageView? Something like `if ([touch view] == myArray)`?

Comment: @RockBaby - no, this test won't tell you something useful. I would test something like : `[myArray containsObject:[touch view]]`.

Answer (score 0):

As the other poster said, use tags. Though, his code is a bit messy. I'd never call properties in the way he did. You should rather do

```
[touch view].tag
```

In this way it will be much easier for other people to read your code. Also, you can set the tags of the UIImageViews like so:

```
yourImageView.tag = 1
```

where the yourImageView is the image.

Answer (score 0):

Give tag value for each image in loop

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
view.tag=i
}
```

Comment: thanks. that's what i'm doing now. i was thinking is there any way without looping

Comment: you can use NSpredicate its easy with out looping